# Correct way to type casting in c++11 style?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

I have a class like this:

```
class A {
    void init(int a){
    _data.resize(a); //! (1)
    }

    //other parts of the code are not important ...
private:
    std::list<std::vector<double>> _data;
}
```

In (1) i got warning with text:

```
implicit conversion from int to size_type(aka unsigned long)
```

I want to know what is the correct way to get rid of that warning?
Maybe something like that:

```
_data.resize(static_cast<decltype(_data)::size_type>(a)
```

**Note:** I guess that the code should be changed to:

```
init(size_t a)
```

But let's assume that we can not change the class interface.

Comment: `init(size_t a){`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I guess that this is the right way, but let us assume that we can not change interface

Comment: Rather than casting anything, it seems more useful to *check* whether the argument is representable as the container's size type.

Comment: With not-using c++11 I would say a simple static_cast<size_t>() would do the job, with c++11 using decltype instead of size_t looks better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example cast does it the right way:

1. It explicitely states intent to cast.
2. It casts to the correct type and is protected from future `_data` type changes.
3. It uses the right cast.

So stick with it, if changing interface is out of question.

It would be good to add sanity checks for input before you will use it. Checking for negative value before you cast it to unsigned is most basic and useful one.

Comment: I'm tempted to add: Check for negative `a` prior to cast.

Comment: You could look into numeric_cast from boost, which will do the range checking for you

Answer (score 4):

The most correct way is as you say:

```
_data.resize(static_cast<decltype(_data)::size_type>(a));
```

But the big problem is signed *vs* `unsigned` and you say you're stuck with `int` so you use:

```
_data.resize(static_cast<unsigned int>(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

As simple as this:

```
_data.resize(std::size_t(a));
```

---

As crazy as this:

```
_data.resize(static_cast<std::size_t>(a));
```

---

C-style casts also supported:

```
_data.resize((std::size_t)a);
```

Comment: As a sidenote, the first suggestion (functional cast) and the c-style cast are two ways to write the same thing.

Comment: @user2079303, I know. The intent of my answer was to show that there exist several ways of doing the same thing. So here you go :)

Comment: I'm sure *you* know. But I doubt everyone looking for *the correct way to cast* would know.